# how to add marker in a captured polygon area in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

**I have drawn a polygon using latitude and longitude collection.**

`mPolylineOptions.addAll(mLatLngCollection);
                mMap.addPolygon(mPolylineOptions);`

Now how to add markers in that polygon area finding the maximum and minimum distance of that area.
**Is it possible to add markers in that polygon???**

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://moduscreate.com/blog/placing-markers-inside-polygons-with-google-maps/) article.

Comment: its a javascript code I need java code for Android.

Comment: So, just convert.

Answer (score 0):

1. first get polygon east, west, south, north boundaries,
2. find random  latitude position between east to west and longitude position between north to south [checkout this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163044/mapbox-how-to-generate-a-random-coordinate-inside-a-polygon)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163044/mapbox-how-to-generate-a-random-coordinate-inside-a-polygon